# add link programmatically to views field Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I am generating views result using ldap query and eliminating some result by checking it against Drupal node title using hook_views_pre_render() and looping through views result.

I want to add link to this ldap views using Drupal node id.

Tried adding in the same pre_render function using drupal l() function. But it displays full html i.e

```
    <a href='node/nid'>title</a>
```

instead of html.

Can anyone help resolving this issue?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coding why you don't use views fields.

1. Add the title and node id fields to the view.
2. Exclude them from display.
3. Add a global: custom text field.
4. Use tokens to print the HTML you want.

It should look like this:

```
<a href="/node/[nid]">[title]</a>
```

Comment: I have to programmatically because results are generated using ldap views and can't add relation to node using ldap view.

Comment: If you have the node ID you can load the node object using node_load function. then you will have access to the node title.

Comment: How to link it programmatically? Without Views interface?

Comment: I have got the full url to be linked. Not sure how to link

Comment: Managed getting links by creating a template file for that particular view only